# Convert shape into a shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, convert

I seek for a way to convert, in the print composer, shape into shapefile.
I added rectangle in the print composer with "Add shape" function

[image]
[image]

I try Rectangles ovals digitizing plugin, but in create shape files outside the print composer. In the ArcGIS, I can do in with "Convert Graphics to features" function

Comment: In ArcGIS layout view also you cannot convert graphics drawn inside layout view to features. You can just do it inside data view but not in layout view. It is also clearly mentioned when you click on "Convert Graphics to features" inside layout view that it is "disabled inside layout view"

Comment: you right i got confused...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot convert shapes located in map composer to a vector shapefile. You are simply adding graphic objects to a layout, which do not have any spatial reference nor a projection, so I don't think there is a way to do it inside composer.

Comment: They're not even related to a map - you can have multiple maps in a print composition, and shapes and other print composer annotations are not tied to a map, they sit on the page. I suppose a plugin could be written to do this but it would have to ask which map on a composition you wanted the thing referenced to...